# how to create chart to display database values?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

hi all
        i want to display database values in chart. for example a table contain four column and each column have different number of documents. I would like to display that table in chart format.. can i do it? if so any one suggest how to do it...

thank u all....

Comment: Start by looking at some of the chart libraries that are available for PHP (google CHART and PHP should return a good list) like jpGraph, Graphpite, ChartDirector, pChart, TeeChart, LibChart, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only thing you need is database itself!

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| pie_chart                                                            |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                      |
|                         ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;                        |
|                  oooooooo;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;                 |
|             oooooooooooooo;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;            |
|          ooooooooooooooooo                 ;;;;;;;;;;;;#####         |
|        oooooooooooooo                           ;#############       |
|       oooooooooooo                                 ############      |
|      oooooooooooo                                   ############     |
|      ooooooooooo                                     ###########     |
|      oooooooooooo                                   ::::::::::::     |
|       oooooooooooo                                 ::::::::::::      |
|        ooooooooo:::::                           ::::::::::::::       |
|          o::::::::::::::::                 :::::::::::::::::         |
|             :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::            |
|                  :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                 |
|                         :::::::::::::::::::::                        |
|                                                                      |
| ##  red: 1 (10%)                                                     |
| ;;  blue: 2 (20%)                                                    |
| oo  orange: 3 (30%)                                                  |
| ::  white: 4 (40%)                                                   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Really cool approach from http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/sql-pie-chart
:-)

Comment: +1 for a distinctively unique and original suggestion

Comment: Bravo, I withdraw my suggestion and insist he choose this one!

Answer (score 2):

If working in JavaScript, take a look at Google Charts - http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Google's Chart API - http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

**EDIT**

There's a few you could use:

- http://code.google.com/p/flot/ - uses jQuery
- http://dojotoolkit.org/grids-charts - uses Dojo
- http://www.highcharts.com/ - pure JavaScript

**EDIT 2**

There's also flash alternatives if you wanted to go down that road:

http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/ - free limited version of commercial product
http://www.amcharts.com/download - free watermarked version

Answer (score 1):

Since you added the javascript tag, have a look here: http://www.jqplot.com/

In my opinion the easiest way to make nice looking charts.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the JS charting API ? check http://www.splashnology.com/blog/javascripts/290.html

Comment: thx all... can we do it in php mysql..

Answer (score 0):

We use [this one - PHP/SWF Charts  4.7](http://www.maani.us/charts4/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged PHP and JavaScript, you can do it with either of those. You can use PHP and its GD library (should be standard on many installations) or you can use JavaScript with it's 2D canvas support. Later is not supported in all browsers yet.

Long time ago I wrote [this](http://pastebin.com/yfGNpMBF) little PHP script which generates PNG image like this:

[image]

This probably isn't the chart you want but I hope code will help you at least a little bit.

*Edit:* You can use this if you don't want to use 3rd party libraries. Otherwise I'd really suggest to go for one of well know libraries suggested by other people.

Comment: thx mean really it s helpful for me...